# tikz draw tree with extra column

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, trees

[image]

01, 001 and 0001 are not actually "childs".
How do I add K=1,2,3 and K=4 to the left hand column?
And I tried really hard to adjust the distance.
But this is the best I can do.

Thanks.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node{1}
    child{
        node{10}
        child{
            node{100}
            child{
                node{1000}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
            }
            child{
                node{1001}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
            }
        }
        child{
            node{101}
            child{
                node{1010}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
            }
            child{
                node{1011}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
            }
        }
    }
    child{
        node{11}
        child{
            node{110}
            child{
                node{1100}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
            }
            child{
                node{1101}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
            }
        }
        child{
            node{111}
            child{
                node{1110}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
            }
            child{
                node{1111}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
            }
        }
    }
    child{
        node{01} edge from parent[draw=none]
        child{
            node{010}
            child{
                node{0100}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
            }
            child{
                node{0101}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
            }
        }
        child{
            node{011}
            child{
                node{0110}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
            }
            child{
                node{0111}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
            }
        }
        child{
            node{001} edge from parent[draw=none]
            child{
                node{0010}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
            }
            child{
                node{0011}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
            }
            child{
                node{0001} edge from parent[draw=none]
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
            }
        }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Tikz tree drawing with comments to each level](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63612)

Comment: @AlanMunn I agree that the first part (the one regarding the labels) is a duplicate of the question you linked to; the other part (a way to draw the four trees), is not a duplicate (at least not of the linked question).

Comment: @AlanMunn I'm glad this is still here, at least, as these questions are now importantly different from my admittedly idiosyncratic point of view! (One wants `justtrees`, I think. The other wants `prooftrees`. Or so I claim.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the first part of your question (placing the labels to the left) the idea is to place names to the nodes on the left-most branch and then use these names to place the labels. For the second part, I'd suggest you to draw each tree separately using `scope`s:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,positioning}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=0.8,
level 1/.style={sibling distance=12em},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=6em},
level 3/.style={sibling distance=3em},
level 4/.style={sibling distance=2em},
]
\node (k1) {1}
    child{
        node (k2) {10}
        child{
            node (k3) {100}
            child{
                node (k4) {1000}
                child{node {$\vdots$}}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
            }
            child{
                node{1001}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
            }
        }
        child{
            node{101}
            child{
                node{1010}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
            }
            child{
                node{1011}
                child{node {$\vdots$}}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
            }
        }
    }
    child{
        node (11) {11}
        child{
            node{110}
            child{
                node{1100}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
            }
            child{
                node{1101}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
            }
        }
        child{
            node{111}
            child{
                node{1110}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
            }
            child{
                node{1111}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
            }
        }
};
\node[left=of k4] (aux) {$k=4$};
\foreach \val \i in {1,2,3} 
  \node at (aux|-k\i) {$k=\i$};
\begin{scope}[
level 1/.style={sibling distance=8em},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=4em},
level 3/.style={sibling distance=2em},
]
\node[right=3.5cm of 11]{01}
        child{
            node  {010}
            child{
                node  {0100}
                child{node {$\vdots$}}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
            }
            child{
                node{0101}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
            }
        }
        child{
            node (011) {011}
            child{
                node{0110}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
            }
            child{
                node{0111}
                child{node {$\vdots$}}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
            }
        };
\end{scope}    
\begin{scope}[
level 1/.style={sibling distance=4em},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=2em},
]
\node[right=1.5cm of 011] {001}
            child{
                node (0010) {0010}
                child{node {$\vdots$}}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
            }
            child{
                node{0011}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
                child{node{$\vdots$}}
            };
\end{scope}    
\begin{scope}[
level 1/.style={sibling distance=1.5em},
]
\node[right=1.2cm of 0010] {0001}
                child{node {$\vdots$}}
                child{node{$\vdots$}
            };
\end{scope}    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Perhaps you could be interested in the powerful [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) package.

Answer (score 1):

This answer uses version 0.07 of an experimental package, `prooftrees`. This is based on `forest` and all of the magic is being done by that package. The key `single branches` is provided by `prooftrees` and is needed to get the spacing right in this case. `\linecountformat` is also provided by the package (and was added for the purpose of answering this question - I'm trying to figure out what kinds of things might be actually useful to people other than me). It is renewed here to change the format of the numbers on the left.

The alignments of `k=1`, `k=2` etc. are managed automatically, as are the values `1`, `2` and so on. A couple of `phantom` nodes are used to get the placement of the trees to the right of the initial one correct, and `forest`'s power is used to automatically specify most nodes' content. Only the content for the tree root nodes and the structure of the trees needs to be manually specified.

If you wish to try this at home, note that this is all very dodgy. Let me know and I will post an updated copy of the package for you. (The one on this site already is version 0.06 which doesn't let you change the format of the line numbers.)

***Caveat emptor...***

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{prooftrees}% v0.07

\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}
  {
    TeX={\renewcommand*\linecountformat[1]{k=#1}},
    for tree={
      before typesetting nodes={
        if content={}{
          if n=1{
            content/.wrap pgfmath arg={#1{}0}{content("!u")},
          }{
            if n'=1{
              content/.wrap pgfmath arg={#1{}1}{content("!u")},
            }{}
          }
        }{}
      },
      tier/.wrap pgfmath arg={tier #1}{level()}
    },
    single branches
  }
  [1
    [
      [
        []
        []
      ]
      [
        []
        []
      ]
    ]
    [
      [
        []
        []
      ]
      [
        []
        []
      ]
    ]
  ]
  [, phantom
    [01
      [
        []
        []
      ]
      [
        []
        []
      ]
    ]
  ]
  [, phantom
    [, phantom
      [001
        []
        []
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

[image: automated tree drawing with <code>prooftrees</code>]