# Position text elements as column in tikz

Tags: tikz-trees

I am using the `tikz` package to draw a tree in `Latex`:

[image]

I am not satisfied with the position of `$h=i$` to the right of the nodes

```
X,X_2,X_6 and X_12.
```

In my code below I used `label=right` which puts it directly beside the node.
My goal is to display `h=1,h=2,h=3,h=4` in a column, i.g. all with same horizontal position (for example all above h=3). Is this possible with tikz?

Code:

```
        \begin{tikzpicture}[level/.style={sibling distance=60mm/#1}]
        \node [circle,draw,label=right:{\textit{h=0}}] (z){$X$}
        child {node [circle,draw] (a) {$X_1$}
            child {node [circle,draw] (c) {$X_3$}
                child {node [rectangle,draw,label=below:1] (e) {$X_7$}}
                child {node [circle,draw] (f) {$X_8$}
                    child {node [rectangle,draw,label=below:2] (g) {$X_{13}$}}
                    child {node [rectangle,draw,label=below:4] (h) {$X_{14}$}}
                }
            }
            child {node [circle,draw] (d) {$X_4$}}
        }
        child {node [circle,draw,label=right:{\textit{h=1}}] (b) {$X_2$}
            child {node [circle,draw] (i) {$X_5$}
                child {node [circle,draw] (k) {$X_9$}
                    child {node [rectangle,draw,label=below:2] (o) {$X_{15}$}}
                    child {node [rectangle,draw,label=below:3] (p) {$X_{16}$}}
                }
                child {node [rectangle,draw,label=below:1] (l) {$X_{10}$}}
            }
            child {node [circle,draw,label=right:{\textit{h=2}}] (j) {$X_6$}
                child {node [rectangle,draw, label=below:3] (m) {$X_{11}$}}
                child {node [circle,draw,label=right:{\textit{h=3}}] (n) {$X_{12}$}
                    child {node [rectangle,draw, label=below:5] (q) {$X_{17}$}}
                    child {node [rectangle,draw, label=below:4] (r) {$X_{18}$}}
                }
            }
        };
        \path (a)--(b) node [midway] {Split 1};
        \path (c)--(d) node [midway] {Split 2};
        \path (i)--(j) node [midway] {Split 3};
        \path (e)--(f) node [midway] {\tiny{Split 4}};
        \path (k)--(l) node [midway] {\tiny{Split 5}};
        \path (m)--(n) node [midway] {\tiny{Split 6}};


        \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. See if http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63625/586 helps.

Answer (score 4):

Like this?

[image]

This is simple to obtain with separated nodes aligned right of node `n`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance=1mm,
C/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=1.5em},
R/.style = {rectangle, draw, minimum size=1.5em},
level/.style={sibling distance=60mm/#1}]
\node [C] (z){$X$}
child {node [C] (a) {$X_1$}
    child {node [C] (c) {$X_3$}
        child {node [R,label=below:1] (e) {$X_7$}}
        child {node [C] (f) {$X_8$}
            child {node [R,label=below:2] (g) {$X_{13}$}}
            child {node [R,label=below:4] (h) {$X_{14}$}}
        }
    }
    child {node [C] (d) {$X_4$}}
}
child {node [C] (b) {$X_2$}
    child {node [C] (i) {$X_5$}
        child {node [C] (k) {$X_9$}
            child {node [R,label=below:2] (o) {$X_{15}$}}
            child {node [R,label=below:3] (p) {$X_{16}$}}
        }
        child {node [R,label=below:1] (l) {$X_{10}$}}
    }
    child {node [C] (j) {$X_6$}
        child {node [R, label=below:3] (m) {$X_{11}$}}
        child {node [C] (n) {$X_{12}$}
            child {node [R, label=below:5] (q) {$X_{17}$}}
            child {node [R, label=below:4] (r) {$X_{18}$}}
        }
    }
};
\node[right=of z -| n.east]  {$h=0$};
\node[right=of b -| n.east]  {$h=1$};
\node[right=of j -| n.east]  {$h=2$};
\node[right=of n.east]       {$h=3$};
\path (a) -- node {Split 1}     (b) 
      (c) -- node {Split 2}     (d)
      (i) -- node {Split 3}     (j)
      (e) -- node [font=\scriptsize] {Split 4}  (f)
      (k) -- node [font=\scriptsize] {Split 5}  (l)
      (m) -- node [font=\scriptsize] {Split 6}  (n);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I take oportunita and make your code slightly shorter with defining two nodes styles: `C` for circle shape and `R` for rectangle shape. For nodes positioning is used TikZ library `positioning`.