# Print depth of tree at each level

Tags: forest

I am using `forest` package to create a tree. However I wanted to print depth number at each level of tree (like Level 1 and Level 2 in below figure).

[image]

I already have tree created.  Code for same is below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Temp}
\author{mjain8 }
\date{May 2017}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
my edge label/.style={
        edge label={node [midway,above,sloped, font=\tiny] {$#1$}}
    },
for tree={%
    l sep=1.5cm,
    s sep=0.2cm,
    minimum height=1.5cm,
    minimum width=1.7cm,
    align=left
    },
    my label/.style={
        label={[anchor=south,font=\scriptsize,red]:#1},
    },
    max label/.style={
        label={[anchor=south,font=\scriptsize]:#1},
    },
    level label/.style={
        label={[font=\scriptsize]left:#1},
    },
    [A,draw,circle,my label={1},max label={maxprofit:0},level label={$i_1$}
        [B,draw,circle,my edge label={\{i_1\}},my label={2},max label={maxprofit:10}
            [D,draw,circle,my edge label={\{i_1,i_2\}},my label={3},max label={maxprofit:40}
                [E,draw,circle,my edge label={\{i_1,i_2,i_3\}},my label={4},max label={maxprofit:80}
                    [F,draw,circle,my edge label={\{i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4\}},my label={5}]
                    [G,draw,circle,my edge label={\{i_1,i_2,i_3\}},my label={6}]
                ]
                [H,draw,circle,my edge label={\{i_1,i_2\}},my label={7}]
            ]
            [I,draw,circle,my edge label={\{i_1\}},my label={8}
                [J5,draw,circle,my edge label={\{i_1,i_3\}},my label={9}
                    [K,draw,circle,my edge label={\{i_1,i_3,i_4\}},my label={10 : F as 17>16}]
                    [L,draw,circle,my edge label={\{i_1,i_3\}},my label={11 : B as 50<80}]
                ]
                [M,draw,circle,my edge label={\{i_1\}},my label={9 : B as 60 < 80}]
            ]
        ]
        [N,draw,circle,my edge label={\{\}},my label={12}
            [O,draw,circle,my edge label={\{i_2\}},my label={13}
                [P,draw,circle,my edge label={\{i_2,i_3\}},my label={14}
                    [Q,draw,circle,my edge label={\{i_2,i_3,i_4\}},my label={15 : F as 17>16}]
                    [R,draw,circle,my edge label={\{i_2,i_3\}},my label={16}]
                ]
                [S,draw,circle,my edge label={\{i_2\}},my label={17}]
            ]
            [T,draw,circle,my edge label={\{\}},my label={18}
                [U,draw,circle,my edge label={\{i_3\}},my label={19}
                    [V,draw,circle,my edge label={\{i_3,i_4\}},my label={20},max label={maxprofit:90}]
                ]
                [W,draw,circle,my edge label={\{\}},my label={21: B as 50<90}]
            ]
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

I tried reading forest documentation but seems nothing is mentioned in documentation related to same.

Can some one please suggest how can this be done?

Comment: Please (1) provide the code for your tree (or a minimal version, if it is large), preferably as a complete but minimal document we can compile; (2) explain what you are trying to do. Where do you want to insert the level number exactly? Do you want the actual level number (starting from 0) or numbered levels (starting from 1)?

Comment: I've re-tagged as this is not specific to the pdfTeX  compiler, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @cfr - I edited the question to include same. Please let me know if you need any other information from me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tikz tree drawing with comments to each level](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63612/tikz-tree-drawing-with-comments-to-each-level)

Comment: @AlanMunn - I referred that question already. Answers in that question is not for forest package and making those changes in my code is not giving expected output. I am quite new to TeX so I may be wrong.

Comment: Actually, my answer there uses Forest.

Comment: I've now rewritten my answer in the question @AlanMunn linked. It is now much less dubious. Actually, it is now as safe as any of my Forest answers, which are probably safer than most of my answers on other topics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this? The tree had a lot of labels already, but I added the sans-serif ones at the left as shown in your image.

[image: level labels]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  my edge label/.style={
    edge label={node [midway,above,sloped, font=\tiny] {$#1$}}
  },
  for tree={%
    l sep=1.5cm,
    s sep=0.2cm,
    minimum height=1.5cm,
    minimum width=1.7cm,
    align=left,
    circle,
    draw,
  },
  my label/.style={
    label={[anchor=south,font=\scriptsize,red]:#1},
  },
  max label/.style={
    label={[anchor=south,font=\scriptsize]:#1},
  },
  level label/.style={
    label={[font=\scriptsize]left:#1},
  },
  before drawing tree={
    tikz+={
      \node [anchor=mid east, font=\sffamily] (m) at (current bounding box.west |- .mid) {Level 1};
    },
    tempcounta'=1,
    for tree={
      if={% if the current level exceeds the value of tempcounta
        >OR>{level}{tempcounta}%
      }{% then step the count and add the level marker
        tempcounta'+=1,
        tikz+/.process={ Rw {tempcounta} {
            \node [anchor=mid east, font=\sffamily] at (m.east |- .mid) {Level #1};
          }%
        },
      }{},
    },
  },
  [A, my label={1},max label={maxprofit:0},level label={$i_1$}
    [B, my edge label={\{i_1\}},my label={2},max label={maxprofit:10}
      [D, my edge label={\{i_1,i_2\}},my label={3},max label={maxprofit:40}
        [E, my edge label={\{i_1,i_2,i_3\}},my label={4},max label={maxprofit:80}
          [F, my edge label={\{i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4\}},my label={5}]
          [G, my edge label={\{i_1,i_2,i_3\}},my label={6}]
        ]
        [H, my edge label={\{i_1,i_2\}},my label={7}]
      ]
      [I, my edge label={\{i_1\}},my label={8}
        [J5, my edge label={\{i_1,i_3\}},my label={9}
          [K, my edge label={\{i_1,i_3,i_4\}},my label={10 : F as 17>16}]
          [L, my edge label={\{i_1,i_3\}},my label={11 : B as 50<80}]
        ]
        [M, my edge label={\{i_1\}},my label={9 : B as 60 < 80}]
      ]
    ]
    [N, my edge label={\{\}},my label={12}
      [O, my edge label={\{i_2\}},my label={13}
        [P, my edge label={\{i_2,i_3\}},my label={14}
          [Q, my edge label={\{i_2,i_3,i_4\}},my label={15 : F as 17>16}]
          [R, my edge label={\{i_2,i_3\}},my label={16}]
        ]
        [S, my edge label={\{i_2\}},my label={17}]
      ]
      [T, my edge label={\{\}},my label={18}
        [U, my edge label={\{i_3\}},my label={19}
          [V, my edge label={\{i_3,i_4\}},my label={20},max label={maxprofit:90}]
        ]
        [W, my edge label={\{\}},my label={21: B as 50<90}]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks!. I was looking for same. I will try to understand the code to make changes as per my requirement.